# Couchbase client how connect to server

Tags: java, couchbase, spymemcached

I want to know how the java coucbase client send values(byte arrays) to couchbase ? is it only a socket connection ? how the couchbase accepts it and read it? As far as I know the couchbase client has extended the spymemcache client.

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase uses the memcached protocol in order to communicate with the server using a network connection. Couchbase also contains an extended command set containing operations not supported by memcached.

Comment: Thank you. where I can find any Sample code explanation how to implement it in my application? I looked internet,, but no luck. I user normal `HttpClient` to communicate between the client and server. It sounds that the memcached can transfer data faster than normal HttpClient. I do not need keep any state/session management. Just communicate fast between my server and client.

Comment: I would start by downloading one of the SDK's and looking through the documentation on the Couchbase website. There are many examples there for each SDK.

http://www.couchbase.com/download